# elasticache redis endpoint keeps returning error timeout

Tags: node.js, redis, amazon-elasticache

I keep getting connection error timeout when i'm trying to connect to elasticache endpoint from my local pc.

```
redis-cli -h foo.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379


//error:
Could not connect to Redis at test-001.ddkmsj.0001.apse3.cache.amazonaws.com:6379: Operation timed out
```

here are my elasticache settings:

```
Node type:
cache.t3.small
Status:
Available
Engine:
Redis
Engine version:
7.0.7
Update status:
Up to date
Cluster mode:
Disabled
Shards:
1
Number of nodes:
1
Multi-AZ:
Disabled
Auto-failover:
Disabled
Encryption in transit:
Disabled
Encryption at rest:
Disabled
Parameter group:
default.redis7
```

and I have the security group to open all traffic for inbound and outbound rules. Any clues how to solve this issue?

Fyi, initially I tried to connect to elasticache from my nodejs script using ioredis:

```
import redis from 'ioredis';
const cluster = new redis({
    host: 'foo.cache.amazonaws.com',
    port: 6379,
    retryStrategy: (times) => {
        if (times <= 3) {
            console.log("1")
            // Retry for a maximum of 3 times
            return Math.min(times * 100, 2000);
        }
        return null; // Do not retry further
    },
    connectTimeout: 600000, 
})
const checkCache = async (req, res, next) => {
    const redisKey = req.originalUrl;
    console.log(">>> connecting to cluster, and fetch")
    cluster.get(redisKey, (err, data) => {
        console.log(">>> inside cluster")
    });
};
```

but it just got stuck on console.log(">>> connecting to cluster, and fetch") and then return connection error timeout.